# How to upload image with Codeigniter frame work?

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2, image-upload

I require help with Image upload code with CodeIgniter. Please refer to my code below

I did try File Upload class, but I am failing on using it on already created code for adding new Products.

This is my Form

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/admin/Welcome/add_new_product'; ?>" method="POST">
  <section class="content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="box box-info">
          <div class="box-header">
            <h3 class="box-title">Product description
              <small></small>
            </h3>


            <h1><input type="textarea" name="pd_title" placeholder="Enter Title Here" style="width:100%;"></h1>
          </div>
          <!-- /.box-header -->
          <div class="box-body pad">

                  <textarea id="editor1" name="pd_short_desc" rows="10" cols="80">
                                          This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
                  </textarea>
                </div>
                  <div class="box-body pad">
                  <label for="Image">Upload Image</label>
                  <input type="file" name="pd_img" value="" style="padding:10px;">
                </div>

                  <div class="box-body pad">
                  <h3 class="box-title">Description to right of Image</h3>
                  <textarea id="editor2" name="pd_info_right" rows="10" cols="80">
                                          This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
                  </textarea>
                </div>
                  <div class="box-body pad">
                  <h3>Product Complete Description</h3>
                  <textarea id="editor3" name="pd_desc" rows="10" cols="80">
                                          This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
                  </textarea>
                </div>

                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn  btn-info btn-raised ink-reaction">
            </form>
```

This is my Controller

```
public function add_new_product()
    {
        $p = $this->model_one->add_new_product();
        redirect('admin/Welcome/view_products');
    }
```

This Model should insert data in mysqli db table

```
public function add_new_product()
{
  $pd_title = $_POST['pd_title'];
  $pd_short_desc = $_POST['pd_short_desc'];
  $pd_image = $_POST['pd_image'];
  $pd_info_right = $_POST['pd_info_right'];
  $pd_desc = $_POST['pd_desc'];

  $sql = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO products (pd_title, pd_short_desc, pd_image, pd_info_right, pd_desc)
  VALUES('$pd_title','$pd_short_desc', '$pd_image','$pd_info_right','$pd_desc')");

  return "yes";
}
```

When submit this form, Image needs to upload in uploads folder, as well insert into products table in mysqli db.

Comment: This is missing from form page <form action="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/admin/Welcome/add_new_product'; ?>" method="POST">. Also public function add_new_product()
    {
        $p = $this->model_one->add_new_product();
        redirect('admin/Welcome/view_products');
    } is Controller I am using.

Comment: Please add complete code where you have problem.

Comment: This is missing from form page <form action="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/admin/Welcome/add_new_product'; ?>" method="POST">. Also public function add_new_product() { $p = $this->model_one->add_new_product(); redirect('admin/Welcome/view_products'); } is Controller I am using

Comment: Where is the controller function to upload image? Add code in the question not comment box

Comment: Sorry about that. Just updated my Question. Please review.

Comment: @DanishAli uploads folder

Comment: Folder inside or outside the project directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do some changes

**View**

Add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the `<form>` tag

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/admin/Welcome/add_new_product'; ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

**Controller**

Get `POST` values in the controller

```
public function add_new_product()
{
    $data = array('pd_title' => $_POST['pd_title'], 'pd_short_desc' => $_POST['pd_short_desc'], 'pd_info_right' => $_POST['pd_info_right'], 'pd_desc' => $_POST['pd_desc']);

    $config['upload_path'] = FCPATH.'uploads/'; 
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png'; 
    $config['max_size'] = 100; 
    $config['max_width'] = 1024; 
    $config['max_height'] = 768;

    if(isset($_FILES['pd_img']['name'])){
       $this->load->library('upload', $config);
       if(!$this->upload->do_upload('pd_img')){ 
           print_r($this->upload->display_errors());
       }else{
           $data['pd_image'] = $this->upload->data('file_name');
       }
    }

    $this->model_one->add_new_product($data);
    redirect('admin/Welcome/view_products');
}
```

**Model**

```
public function add_new_product($data)
{
    return $this->db->insert('products', $data);
}
```

Comment: if(isset($_FILES['pd_img']['name']))
  {
        //Image uploading...
            $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
                $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['max_size']             = 100;
                $config['max_width']            = 1024;
                $config['max_height']           = 768;
              $this->upload->do_upload('pd_image');
    } No Success, image is uploading in uploads folder but not getting aded to sqli db

Comment: Try this in the controller `if( !$this->upload->do_upload('pd_image')){ print_r($this->upload_display_errors());}` to get any error message

Comment: public function add_new_product()
{
    $data = array('pd_title' => $_POST['pd_title'], 'pd_short_desc' => $_POST['pd_short_desc'], 'pd_info_right' => $_POST['pd_info_right'], 'pd_desc' => $_POST['pd_desc']);

    if( !$this->upload->do_upload('pd_image')){ print_r($this->upload_display_errors());}

    $this->model_one->add_new_product($data);
    redirect('admin/Welcome/view_product');
} Is this correct

Comment: No Success - A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Welcome::$upload

Filename: admin/Welcome.php

Line Number: 211

Backtrace:

File: D:\xampnew\htdocs\cms\application\controllers\admin\Welcome.php
Line: 211
Function: _error_handler

File: D:\xampnew\htdocs\cms\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: Let me complete this. First, tell me what is the project directory structure? I mean the targeted folder?

Comment: danish ali uploads folder

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Welcome::upload_display_errors() in D:\xampnew\htdocs\cms\application\controllers\admin\Welcome.php on line 220
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Error

Message: Call to undefined method Welcome::upload_display_errors()

Filename: admin/Welcome.php

Line Number: 220

Backtrace:

Comment: @Riyaz it's `$this->upload->display_errors()`. It was typing issue from my side

Comment: Danish Ali and Alex I thank you for helping me fixing this, Danish your code did work, and now the Image does get added in uploads folder as well in the mysqli db. Thank you again.

Comment: Now as the images are uploading in upload folder and Mysqli, how can images be displayed when viewed online by public.

Comment: First, get the product record from DB and use image name in the `<img>` tag like `<img src="<?= base_url('uploads/'.$image_name)?>" />`